# Eclipse Debug configuration: add parameters #!e on GWT project

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gwt, parameters, url-parameters

I am using Eclipse Indigo to develop a GWT project. At time of debugging I need to set this URL: `http://127.0.0.1:8888/MySite.html#!e` (edition mode)

But instead the one that is opened is `http://127.0.0.1:8888/MySite.html`

How can I add this #!e at time of debugging?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

->Right click in eclipse

->Open debug configuration

->Under arguments tab option,write Mysite.html#!e instead of Mysite.html

-remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}" -startupUrl **MySite.html#!e** -logLevel INFO -codeServerPort 9997 -port 8888 -war {Project Dir Path}